# How to turn off unicode flag in g++ in QT Creator?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qmake

When I compiling some project I see command like

```
g++ -c -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -g -std=gnu++11 -Wall -Wextra -Wextra -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -DMINGW_HAS_SECURE_API=1 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -I..
```

How can I remove `-DUNICODE` and `-D_UNICODE`?

I tried change my `.pro` file:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS -= -DUNICODE
```

but this doesn't work.

Comment: I suppose the question is why you would want to turn off Unicode? When programming on Windows it generally the correct setting to use.

Comment: Why do you want to do it? Would simple `#undef` in code be enough?

Comment: @john  I would like to compile this code: https://github.com/jmscreation/WindowsServiceMinGW. I can only compile it when this flags are not set

Comment: @hyde please look at my comment above

Comment: Note that MS-PL (license of that code, if I didn't misread) may be (probably intentionally) incompatible with not only GPL but also LGPL. It may or may not matter to you, but better be aware.

Answer (score 4):

These identifiers come from the `DEFINES` variable, so we can remove them like this:

```
DEFINES -= UNICODE
DEFINES -= _UNICODE
```